# How to post to my own facebook page with an app?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Facebook Graph Api - Posting to Fan Page as an Admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627684/facebook-graph-api-posting-to-fan-page-as-an-admin)

I've written the code below:

```
$pageId = 'xxx';
$appId = 'xxx';
$secret = 'xxx';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => $appId,
    'secret' => $secret,
    'cookie' => false
));

$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();

$facebook->api("/{$pageId}/feed", "post", array(
    'message' => "First message",
    'name' => "Name for first",
    'access_token' => $access_token
));
```

But getting the following exception: 
(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if the user is logged in yet? Simple, but I don't see it in your code.

You could first check if $facebook->getUser() is null, if null redirect to $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('req_perms' => 'user_status'); and make sure to add other permissions you might need.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6971768/facebook-graph-api-getaccesstoken-not-working) is very similar, read through some of the answers - there should be one that works for you.

Comment: i want to post on behalf of the page, not on any other user

Comment: hmm sorry about that. but based on the error it seems it's checking for an authorized user to do that.

Comment: i get the same error message when i got an access token for the page

Answer (score 0):

You will need *publish_stream* permission in your code.
It can be:

```
$my_url = "http://apps.facebook.com/siegiusarena";
```

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {

```
    $message=$application_name." game on facebook. Check it out: http://apps.facebook.com/siegiusarena";
$link = "http://apps.facebook.com/siegiusarena";
$attachment = array('message'=>$message, 'link'=>$link, 'picture'=>'http://www.developas.com/fb/siegiusarena/siegiusarena_256x256.jpg');
$facebook->api("me/feed", 'post', $attachment);
```

}else{
    $code = $_REQUEST["code"];

```
    if(empty($code)) {
                     $_SESSION['state'] = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE)); // CSRF protection
                     $dialog_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
   . $appid . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url) . "&state="
   . $_SESSION['state'] . "&scope=email,publish_stream";

                    echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");
```

}
}

Comment: PLEASE VOTEUP IF HELPED.

Comment: why do i need to authenticate myself or grant permission if i am the administrator of the app and the page?

Comment: NO YOU COULD BE ADMIN. BUT WHEN APP RUNS IT REQUIRES PERMISSION FROM ANYONE WHO JOINS IT. APPLICATION NEEDS PERMISSION TO PERFORM ACTIONS ACCORDINGLY. AND FOR POSTING TO FEED "publish_stream" IS REQUIRED.

Comment: "publish_stream" IS AN OPTIONAL PERMISSION. IF SOMEONE SKIPS THIS PERMISSION AND DONT ALLOW. YOUR APP WONT BE ABLE TO POST ON THEIR WALL. I HAVE DOZENS OF FACEBOOK APP. AND SEE I HAVE IMPLEMENETED IT HERE: http://apps.facebook.com/siegiusarena

Comment: AND TO MANAGE PAGES YOU WOULD NEED "manage_pages" permission too.

Comment: so i cant post to facebook from a background process?